# is this working ? Update Panel work or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, updatepanel

In c# i can put one button and one textbox (TextBox1) in update panel and also add one textbox in outside update panel. now i write code under button click event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text="This";
    TextBox2.Text= textbox1.text;
}
```

is text of TextBox2 is changed or not?
without fire trigger......

Please Help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `TextBox2` is outside of the update panel it will not update. If it needs to be outside of that update panel, I would consider putting it in another update panel.